# How can I make this custom sidebar well panel reactive to the data changing i.e. add,edit,delete

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make the totals on the left hand reactive to changes to the data table in the main panel but am not having any luck figuring out how and where to insert code to do that . Currently they render only on the application start.

here is the partial code with the functions that display them.
top of app

```
sumDebit <- function(){debitresult <- dbGetQuery(pool,"SELECT sum(debit) as tdebits FROM po.katpay ")
    return(debitresult)
    }
sumCredit <- function(){creditresult <- dbGetQuery(pool,"SELECT sum(credit) as tcredits FROM po.katpay ")
    return(creditresult)
    }
totBalance <- function(){sumDebit() - sumCredit()}
    
sidebarPanel2 <- function (..., out1 = NULL,out2=NULL,out3=NULL,out4=NULL, width = 18) 
    {
      div(class = paste0("col-sm-", width), 
          tags$form(class = "well", ...),out1,out2,out3,out4
      )
    }
```

UI section

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Payment Editor"),
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
  
  
  fluidRow(
        actionButton("add_button", "Add", icon("plus")),
        actionButton("edit_button", "Edit", icon("edit")),
        actionButton("delete_button", "Delete", icon("trash-alt")),
        actionButton("refresh_button", "Refresh", icon("refresh"))
      ),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "group_dims",
        label = "Filter",
        choices = c("date", "debit", "credit","company", "note"),
        selected = c("None"),
        multiple = TRUE
      ), 
     
      sidebarPanel2(fluid = TRUE,
                   
                    out1 = h5("Total Debits = " , formatC(sumDebit(),format="d",big.mark=',')),
                    out2 = h5("Total Credits = ", formatC(sumCredit(),format="d",big.mark=',')),
                    #out3 = tags$hr(style="color:black"),
                    out4 = h5("Balance = ",formatC(totBalance(),format="d",big.mark=',')),
                    ),
    ),
    
    # DT table
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("responses_table") %>% shinycssloaders::withSpinner()),
   
  )
)# end fluidpage
```

the add/edit/delete functions/buttons all work correctly but i am stuck on how to make the values in sidebarpanel2 update on changes. if I add code in the server section I get errors in the ui i.e. cannot find symbol etc . So I guess I am not really understanding how the ui and server are interacting or what labels,definitions etc to pass between them , if that makes sense ?

I have tried making the functions themselves reactive with no luck...  get must be in a reactive container errors

My guess is most of the functions need to be in the server section and i just need fields values in the ui section to fill in but am not figuring out how to do that either.

** did not include server code because it does nothing for this at this point ..

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: There is no trigger to your functions. Which action should trigger `sumDebit()`?

Comment: they are in the server section ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for the next guy ....or to remind me down the road what i assumed shiny would do easily turns out need some js and html to do ..

the key here was the div/classes and id's to be able to select elements  ...i think ...and the basic understanding this is really just a client/server web app.

top section...

```
sidebarPanel2 <- function (..., debit = NULL,credit=NULL,balance=NULL, width = 18)
{
  withTags(
            div(id="well2", class = paste0("col-sm-", width),
                div(class="debit",(debit)), # might not need these classes but works. 
                div(class="credit",(credit)),
                div(class="balance",(balance))
                ) # end div
          ) # end withTags
} # end sidebar2
```

... in the ui section JS to handle server responses ...

```
    # section defines javascript to change values on client
tags$script('
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("DebitHandler",
        function(debit) {
          document.getElementById("debit").innerHTML=debit
        });'),
tags$script('
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("CreditHandler",
        function(credit) {
          document.getElementById("credit").innerHTML=credit
        });'),
tags$script('
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("BalanceHandler",
        function(balance) {
          document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML=balance
        });'),
```

and ....

```
 #create second sidebar 'well' and populate for first run
  sidebarPanel2(fluid=TRUE,
                debit =  h5(id="debit","Total Debits  = ",format(sumDebit(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall =2)),
                credit = h5(id="credit","Total Credits = ", format(sumCredit(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall =2)),
                balance = h5(id="balance","Total Balance = ", format(totBalance(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall=2))
                ), # end sidepanel2
            ), # end sidepanel
```

... and in the server section

```
  #generate new balances and send it back to the client on edits.add.delete
  #handler function called '?????Handler'
  observe({
    debit=paste("Total Debits = ", format(sumDebit(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall =2))
    credit=paste("Total Credits = ", format(sumCredit(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall =2))
    balance=paste("Total Balance = ", format(sumDebit() - sumCredit(),format="d",big.mark=',',nsmall =2))
    
    input$submit                                                                                                            
    input$submit_edit
    input$refresh_button
    input$delete_button
    
    if(input$refresh_button){ 
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="DebitHandler",debit)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="CreditHandler",credit)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="BalanceHandler",balance)
    }
    
    if(input$delete_button){
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="DebitHandler",debit)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="CreditHandler",credit)
      session$sendCustomMessage(type ="BalanceHandler",balance)
    }
  })
```

for some reason the submit and submit_edit work too but no code for them ?
there are a lot of wasted cycles and redundant queries here .. it seems to me but it works.

just for referance this is what well2 html ended up looking like on the client side .

```
<div id="well2" class="col-sm-18">
    <div class="debit">
        <h5 id="debit">Total Debits = 46,456.88</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="credit">
        <h5 id="credit">Total Credits = 18,618.38</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="balance">
        <h5 id="balance">Total Balance = 27,838.50</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside the shiny class "well" input select container